# download JSON file in node Js

Tags: node.js, json, file, export

I am creating a json file, but not sure how to download it. 
here is my code

```
 let jsonExport= directory path;
exportTemp (name, title,  id) {

let obj = new Array() ;
obj.push({Title: name, Prefix:title,  UserId:id });
  let file_name= jsonExport + name + ".json"
 fs.writeFile(file_name, JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4), (err, response) => {
if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
};

   console.log("File has been created");
});

return (file_name);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using express, you can simply do it like this

```
res.download(file_name);
```

or without express

```
app.get('/downloadFile/', (req, res) => {
  var files = fs.createReadStream(file_name);
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=demo.pdf'});
  files.pipe(res)
})
```